# When I zoom in/out the browser window my html index page gets messed up

Tags: html, css

```css
 .box-1 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  
}
}

 .box-2 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
 }
 

 .box-3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

 .box-4 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
}
 

 
 h1 {
  color: white;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
 <div class="box-1">
  
  
 </div>
 <div class="box-2">
  
 </div>
 <div class="box-3">
  
 </div>
 <div class="box-4">
  
 </div>
 

 

</div>
```

enter code hereSOmebody, please help. It''s been a while I start to learn CSS. I now build plain templates as an amateur. But ,one of thing that drives me crazy is that, after finishing structure of a page and finishing styling I zoom in and out the browser page everything gets messed up. texts go crazy to top, banners go bottom etc. I made 30 second video in order to demonstrate this case. please visit this link http://screencast.com/t/aUGFjtQDW

Comment: add your html and css here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to keep being full page, you should use percentages for width, and absolute positioning.

If you want it to scale normally, you need to create another div beneath body, for example "container", and set it's width to whatever you want, in this case 1920px (or your monitor width)

Comment: to use percentages for width? for all elements? divs, images etc?